# Why is a disconnected cold line dribbling water?

Tags: plumbing, pex

A disconnected cold mainline dribbles room temp water from upstream faucets.

I am going to install a water softener but did not have a dedicated line to the kitchen (for unsoftened water). However, in my utility room the main 3/4 pex line branches off many times before leading to the kitchen. So I decided to cut the main line as far downstream as possible in hopes to creating a dedicated kitchen line. Turns out I was wrong and that portion of the mainline fed the kitchen, upstairs bathroom and laundry room.

Here is the problem.. I ran the new “kitchen” line back to the utility room and left it hanging there, turned the water on and left. I came back a bit later and it’s dripping warm water.

To reiterate the situation, I now have two ‘main lines’ one that feed kitchen, one bathroom and laundry room. However this new COLD mainline I hadn’t hooked up yet to the system. It’s dangling there. But it starts dribbling water. I think Luke warm.. but maybe it’s room temp cold water.

Is this a symptom of a bad mixing valve on one of my showers or faucets?

Comment: There's a lot of info here that seems totally extraneous to the question  if you [edit] your question down to just the pertinent facts (dripping water is room temp), that will save a lot of time for people who might want to help you.

Comment: I've read this a couple times (and tried to revise for clarity), but I'm still not getting it. Is the leak on the end of the unused line or at a fixture? Please revise to simplify, clarify, and illuminate us as to the layout, ideally with photos or a diagram.

Comment: To clarify... You have a pex water line that is not connected to the supply yet.. But has been connected to your demand side.. And that is leaking a small amount of water?

Comment: Yes! There is a line that leads to the demand side. Various faucets etc. but not connected to the supply. And the side that should be connected to the supply and receive water. Is dribbling water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagnostic is probably correct, it could be a cheap mixing valve... Alternatively its possible one of your faucets/sinks/shower is slightly open... I don't know.

Do you need to do anything about it? nope. Its a little dribble, The water pressure from your cold water side should be equal (or close to equal) to your hot water pressure... Once your cold supply is connected, you will forget that the leak was ever there.

Comment: Ok that answered my follow up! In the event it’s a defective mixing valve, my fear would be that hot water would back flow and I would be constantly heating my cold side. 

Is this fear valid or will the pressure prevent hot water being wasted to the cold side?

Comment: Its a little drip of water. Your hot water side has a lot more pressure then that drip does... As does your cold water side. The drip of water from one side to the other of the mixer won't exist once both sides have a similar amount of pressure.. If it was gushing water, It would be a problem. But a little drip of water isn't going to cause backflow.

Comment: Your the best! In the event I decide to look for the issue (since I can narrow it to about 4 fixtures. 5 if you include the washing machine). What would I be looking for or replacing? Shower or faucet cartridge or entire fixture

Comment: @Batman I wouldn't. Water isn't gushing out... Once your supply is connected there won't be a problem. Spend your time/money elsewhere.